# Need Uri for Activeperl installation in docker

Tags: docker, perl, docker-for-windows

For my use case, I need to create a windows container of Activeperl application. I found a [GitHub link](https://github.com/kiazhi/Windows-Containers/blob/master/dockerfiles/nanoserver/perl/sac2016-5.26.2.1/Dockerfile) which explains the process for a Strawberry Perl.

Code snippet from the link

```
RUN \
    if(!(Test-Path -Path 'C:\Temp')) \
    { \
        New-Item \
            -Path 'C:\Temp' \
            -ItemType Directory \
            -Verbose | Out-Null ; \
    } ; \
    \   
    Invoke-WebRequest \
        -Uri "http://strawberryperl.com/download/$ENV:PERL_VERSION/strawberry-perl-$ENV:PERL_VERSION-64bit.zip" \
        -OutFile "C:\\Temp\\strawberry-perl-$ENV:PERL_VERSION-64bit.zip" \
        -UseBasicParsing \
        -Verbose ; \
    \
    Expand-Archive \
        -Path "C:\\Temp\\strawberry-perl-$ENV:PERL_VERSION-64bit.zip" \
        -DestinationPath 'C:\Program Files\Perl' \
        -Verbose ; \
    \
    Set-ItemProperty \
        -Path 'HKLM:\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment' \
        -Name 'Path' \
        -Value $($ENV:Path + ';C:\Program Files\Perl\perl\bin;C:\Program Files\Perl\perl\site\bin;C:\Program Files\Perl\c\bin') \
        -Verbose ;
```

Strawberryperl Uri - **http://strawberryperl.com/download/$ENV:PERL_VERSION/strawberry-perl-$ENV:PERL_VERSION-64bit.zip**

For me, I want an equivalent Uri for downloading Activeperl instead of Strawberryperl. I am even ok with a Windows Container Image with activeperl installed already. I just couldn't find any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Since ActivePerl doesn't provide an option for downloading a zipped version of Perl.
This is how I was able to transfer an active Perl to a Windows container

In my host windows machine, I have downloaded the Active Perl from https://activeperl.software.informer.com/download/

The downloaded file is ActivePerl-5.28.1.0000-MSWin32-x64-e90bcbf1.msi
I have installed this at the location C:\Perl64\

Copied this Perl64 folder into a new folder called Perl_root, so that this can be copied into the container via Dockerfile. Create a file called Dockerfile in the same location as Perl_root.

Filesystem_Root

```
C:\
 |__ docker_trial
     |___ Perl_root
     |___ Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile:

```
#pulled a windows container from docker hub
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1607-amd64

ADD Perl_root .
```

Open a command prompt and navigate to the folder where dockerfile is present.

```
>docker build --tag dockertrail:1.0 .
>docker run -it --name tag1 dockertrail:1.0
```

Once the terminal inside the docker container opens up, open a PowerShell and create the update the environment variable Path as below

```
Powershell>[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path",$env:Path+"C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin","Machine")
```

exit from the PowerShell and container. Now restart the container tag1, for the environment variable to work.

start the container tag1 again, once it starts, open up a PowerShell and run the command `$env:Path`  you must be able to see the perl path being added to environment variables.

Now check the functioning of Perl using the command `perl -v`
This should print the perl verion.
[image]